# How to access the image url inside a function app

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am writing a function app to send emails and I want the email to include an embedded image which is hosted on my different website.
I am using AlternativeViews and adding it to my MailMessage object like so -

`mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(GetEmbeddedImage(@"https://some_domain/xmas.jpg"));`

However, the LinkedResource in GetEmbeddedImage is the one throwing an error, if the filePath is an url address like this - https://some_domain/xmas.jpg -

```
        private AlternateView GetEmbeddedImage(string filePath)
        {            
            LinkedResource res = new LinkedResource(filePath);
            res.ContentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            string imageMarkup = @"<img src='cid:" + res.ContentId + @"' height='100' width='100'/>";

            string htmlBody = @"<html>
                      <body>
                      <p><b>Dear Mr. XYZ,</b></p>" + imageMarkup +    
                      @"<p>some message here</p>
                      <p>Kind Regards,<br></br></p>
                      </body>
                      </html>
                     ";

            AlternateView alternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
            alternateView.LinkedResources.Add(res);

            return alternateView;
        }
```

The error message is
`The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. : 'C:\mylocal\EmailFunctionApp\FunctionAppEmailer\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\https:\my_domain\xmas.jpg'`

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.linkedresource.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Mail_LinkedResource__ctor_System_String_) say that in `LinkResource(filePath)` you should use: "The file name holding the content for this embedded resource.".  You are using an URL, and that's why you get a message stating: "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." . So , what is the problem?

Comment: Thats exactly what I was after @ChetanRanpariya , however I now get 401 Unauthorised error. The image is hosted on my Azure.

Comment: Well that's a different issue to solve. You might want to look at the permissions/policies associated with the image on azure

Comment: Thanks both issues resolved. I found the anonymous access url, Resolved. Thanks a lot.